# Update netbeans 7.3 to latest version

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-7

How do I update netbeans for my mac. Whenever I try to update using **Check for updates**, I see "Your IDE is up to date!". Is there another way to update the exisitng IDE without downloading the installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, check for updates is for installing patches and updates of current version. If you want 7.4 or 8.0, you need to download it and install it manually